# Постоянная проблема при верстке блока с картинками

Tags: html, css

Скажу сразу что верстать я умею) и на нативном CSS\HTML и на Bootstrap. Но всегда натыкаюсь на одну и ту же проблему! Я не понимаю как верстать блок в котором идут картинки (например примеры работ или что то подобное). Кто может раз и навсегда объяснить как это делается. Мне нужно знать несколько вариантов, допустим есть блок обертка и в нем по порядку идут картинки, как сделать что бы они были одинакового размера и при изменении окна браузера они так же и оставались, насколько я понимаю это делают через "%" но у меня не выходит что то. Второй вариант это картинки между которыми есть промежутки (то есть но не прилипают к друг другу), когда я делаю отступы то все выпадает и верстка ломается, нужно что бы любое кол-во картинок оставалось в своем блоке при ресайзе окна. Я думаю вы поняли что я имел тут ввиду. Приведу в пример набросок кода, если не сложно покажите что да как

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title>Document</title>
  <style>
   .container {
    width: 1000px;
    height: auto;
    border: 1px solid #bbb;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }

  .item {
    width: 25%;
    height: 160px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.4);
  }</style>
</head>
<body>
   <div class="container">
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

[Пример кода для редактирования](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eJWvWv)

Comment: мне кажется стоит посмотреть в сторону [`display:flex`](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Comment: посмотрите такой вариант - https://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/635zr6ux/

Answer (score 2):

### По примеру:

1. Если дочерним элементам указываете ширину в процентах и дополнительные свойства такие как `border` или `padding`, то не забывайте указывать `box-sizing: border-box`.
2. Если дочерным элементам указываете `display: inline-block` **без** `float` и хотите, что бы между ними не было **не контролируемых** отступов, то не забывайте добавлять комментарии `<!-- -->` между элементами для горизонтального сброса и `vertical-align: top;` для вертикального сброса.

### По вопросу:

Данная задача лучше всего решается с помощью `fluid grid`. Проще говоря используется резиновая сетка.

**1.** Если у элементов не должно быть отсупов, то считаете кол-во элементов в строке и задаете ширину = `100 / <кол-во элементов в строке>`%.

**2.** Намного интереснее задача, когда нужны отсупы между дочерними элементами. 
Обычно два подхода: через `margin` или через `padding`.

**Отступ через margin**:
Ширина задается примерно так же, только еще минус отступ.
А вот тут вопрос. Отступ в процентах или в px/em/rem? И начинаются расчеты, и появляются 'красивые цифры', `margin: 3.45677%`  или `margin: 12.45354px` и т.д. + нужно первому или последнему элементу этот отступ сбрасывать. Одним словом - **'красота'**.

**Отступ через padding**:
Куда гибче, проще и легче способ задания отступов через `padding`.
Вся магия заключается в использовании `box-sizing: border-box;`

Ширина элемента = `100 / <кол-во элементов в строке>`%.
Отступ между элементами = `padding * 2`. Т.е. если между элементами должен быть отступ в `10px`, значит `padding: 5px;`. Если только по горизонтали, то `padding-left: 5px; padding-right: 5px`. По вертикали соответственно.
Если нужны отступы в процентах, то поступаем аналогично.
При таком исспользовании нужно оговорится, по бокам создаются отступы, что бы их убрать **родительскому** контейнеру задаются отрицательные марджины.
`<parent margin>= - <child padding>`.

Либо мы задаем `padding` в одном направлении, например всем элементам задаем `padding-left` = отступ между элементами, но тогда надо сбрасывать у первого элементами в строке или `padding-right` и у последнего элемента.

Советую обратить внимание на самую простую и гибкую сетку, на мой взгляд, [pocketgrid](http://arnaudleray.github.io/pocketgrid/) (когда нажмете download, поймете о чем я говорю)

---

Недавно увидел немного другой подход, через [calc](https://github.com/peterramsing/lost), тоже заслуживает внимание, но я пока до нее не дошел.

**Небольшое отступление про изображения**
При использовании резиновой сетки конечно нужно понимать, что изображения не могут выступать в качестве элементов сетки, они должны находится внутри этих элементов и нужно учитывать будут ли изображения одинаковых размеров или разных. И от этого выбирать подход, использовать `img` с `max-width: 100%; height: auto;` или через `background-image` и `background-size` и т.д. (+ выравнивание). Вариантов достаточно.

Answer (score 0):

Это применяют плагин на jquery http://masonry.desandro.com/  , посмотрите , так как очень удобно  вот демо в примере

```js
// external js: masonry.pkgd.js

$(document).ready( function() {

  $('.grid').masonry({
    itemSelector: '.grid-item',
    columnWidth: '.grid-sizer',
    percentPosition: true
  });
  
});
```

```css
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
          box-sizing: border-box;
}

body { font-family: sans-serif; }

/* ---- grid ---- */

.grid {
  background: #EEE;
  max-width: 1200px;
}

/* clearfix */
.grid:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

/* ---- grid-item ---- */

.grid-sizer,
.grid-item {
  width: 20%;
}

.grid-item {
  height: 120px;
  float: left;
  background: #D26;
  border: 2px solid #333;
  border-color: hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0.5);
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.grid-item--width2 { width:  40%; }
.grid-item--width3 { width:  60%; }

.grid-item--height2 { height: 200px; }
.grid-item--height3 { height: 260px; }
.grid-item--height4 { height: 360px; }
```

```html
<script src="http://masonry.desandro.com/masonry.pkgd.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Masonry - fluid columnWidth</h1>

<div class="grid">
  <div class="grid-sizer"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item--width2 grid-item--height2"></div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item--height3"></div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item--height2"></div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item--width3"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item--height2"></div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item--width2 grid-item--height3"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item--height2"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item--width2 grid-item--height2"></div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item--width2"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item--height2"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item--height3"></div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item--height2"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item--height2"></div>
</div>
```